# Print the content of /etc/passwd with constant creation limit

Tags: restricted-source, file-system

Rules/Objectives:

1. The program must be executed using `./program-name` without shell parameter/arguments.
2. the `program-name` may not contain any of characters in `/etc/passwd`, that is `acdepstw`
3. You may not open any other file, including own's source code, only `/etc/passwd` that should be read.
4. The program must print the content the `/etc/passwd` file.
5. Total score of the code equal to number of characters in the code added with constant literal declaration point. Each byte of constant declaration literal equal to `+100` to the score, after `3` declaration, each byte adds `+200` to the score. So the program should not contain too many constant declaration, but you may use predeclared constants (`M_PI` for example) or exploit the reflection of the function/variable/class name (function, variable or class names in this case are not considered as constant). Counting example:

   ```
   int x = 12;       // counted as 1 byte (12 can fit to 8-bit)
   x += 345;         // counted as 2 bytes (345 can fit to 16-bit)
   #define Y 'e'     // counted as 1 byte ('e')
   #define X Y       // counted as 0 (not considered as constant)
   string s = "abc"; // counted as 3 bytes ("abc")
   :foo              // counted as 3 bytes (:foo) 
                     //  ^ EACH characters in atom (Elixir, etc) 
                     //    or characters in symbol (Ruby, etc) 
                     //    are counted as 1 byte constant
   ''                // counted as 0 (not considered as constant)
   [0xAC, 12, 114]   // counted as 3 bytes (0xAC, 12, 114)
   ```

**Clarification**:

things that counted as constant literal:

- numbers, each byte, depends on size
- strings/symbols, each character = 1 byte
- chars, one byte

things that not counted as constant literal:

- class declaration
- function declaration
- variable declaration
- operators, brackets
- predefined symbols
- predefined constants

Comment: What about languages like Bash, where everything is equivalent to a literal (ex. `echo -n hello` is the same as `"echo" "-n" "hello"`)?

Comment: echo is function calling so it's not, but `-n` counted as 2 bytes, `hello` counted as 5 bytes

Comment: The scoring rules currently just do not make sense. I think I can figure out the grammatical errors, but they require an unsupplied map between the terms you use and the tokens in a program. E.g. if I were following my best guess at the meaning of the rules, I would give your JS answer a much higher score because of all the symbols it contains (e.g. function names used other than in declarations).

Comment: I'm confused. We're supposed to print the contents of a specific file without reading any files?

Comment: I forgot to add `except /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 49 characters + 0 bytes constant = 49

```
W[JCJFJIJBEIDHDHDHJBKGIJDHKCIHKFKFKJJA]Y/f+Afb:cg
```

It doesn't work in the online interpreter for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

## NodeJS - 179 characters + 1 byte constant declaration = 279

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
fs=function fs(){};fs=require(fs.name);x=function etc(){};y=function passwd(){};z='/';fs.readFile(z+x.name+z+y.name,function(err,data){console.log(''+data);});
```

Readable version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node    
fs = function fs(){};
fs = require(fs.name);
x = function etc(){};
y = function passwd(){};
z = '/'; // 1 declaration
fs.readFile(z+x.name+z+y.name,function(err,data){
  console.log(''+data);
});
```